# How to bind "Encodable" to type parameter?

Tags: generics, types, rust, traits

Context: I am working on a library that needs to pass objects either to another process or over a tcp connection, so I do not want users to care about the way library does serialization.

Is the generic use of "Encodable" possible?

If so, how do I bind "Encodable" type parameter to T, so I can use "Foo.send" method in "main"?

Could it be done in a way that would not require "main" to mention serialization format?

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::{json, Encodable};

struct Foo<T>;

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn send(&self, data: T) {
        // error: failed to find an implementation of trait 
        // serialize::serialize::Encodable<serialize::json::
        // Encoder<'_>,std::io::IoError> for T
        println!("{}", json::Encoder::str_encode(&data));
    }
}

#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct DataX {
    a : int,
}

fn main() {
    let sourceX = DataX { a : 1 };
    let fooX = Foo::<DataX>;
    fooX.send(sourceX);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [bounded type parameter](http://doc.rust-lang.org/tutorial.html#bounded-type-parameters-and-static-method-dispatch) as shown below and [in the playpen](http://is.gd/MUutXn).

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::{json, Encodable, Encoder};
use std::io::{IoError};

struct Foo<T>;

impl<'a, T: Encodable<json::Encoder<'a>, IoError>> Foo<T> {
    fn send(&self, data: T) {
        println!("{}", json::Encoder::str_encode(&data));
    }
}

#[deriving(Encodable)]
struct DataX {
    a : int,
}

fn main() {
    let sourceX = DataX { a : 1 };
    let fooX = Foo::<DataX>;
    fooX.send(sourceX);
}
```

This outputs:

```
{"a":1}
```